# How can I make this PowerShell script into one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

This PowerShell script works great, but I need it to be a one line script, how can I create the parameter objects inline?

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset}'
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Reset IIS" -Description "Daily Reset IIS"
```

e.g.

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Action `New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset}'` -Trigger `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am -TaskName "Reset IIS" -Description "Daily Reset IIS"`
```

I've tried wrapping it in double quotes and with backticks and with curly braces but no luck so far.

Comment: How about parenthesis?

Comment: Backticks are escape characters in PowerShell. Use subexpressions (`$(...)`) or simply separate your statements with semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subexpressions should do it. Brackets outside subexpressions not required AFAIK.

> $( ) Subexpression operator
>
> Returns the result of one or more statements. For a single result,
>   returns a scalar. For multiple results, returns an array.
>   [sauce: about_Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset}') -Trigger $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am)-TaskName "Reset IIS" -Description "Daily Reset IIS"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a subexpression wrap it in $()

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset}') -Trigger $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am) -TaskName "Reset IIS" -Description "Daily Reset IIS"
```